# Vue Animation Script misses the timing

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a web api project and I want to play an animation on one of my html spans.Specificly the vue returns a number and I want that number to animate increasing from 00.00% up to its value.It actually works fine with a js script that I found online if I delete a part of my html but it doesnt work and the numbers appears as 00.00 if I use my entire HTML Code.
Here is my code:

`````````````````````
<html>
<body>

//This is the part that I want to work but appears as 00.00
<span class="Animation">{{number}}</span>%



//This is the part that if I delete it the upper part works but I want both parts in my project
<div v-for="item in items">
<h3>{{item1.name1}}</h3>
<h5 class="prediction-2">Score:{{item2.name2}}%</h5>
<a v-bind:href="'test.html?id=' + item.other_id" class="btn">
<span style="color:white;">click here</span>
</a>
</div>

<script>
$('.Animate').each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                jQuery({
                    Counter: 0
                }).animate({
                    Counter: $this.text()
                }, {
                    duration: 5000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function () {
                        $this.text(this.Counter.toFixed(2));
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
</body>
</html>
````````````````````
`````````````````````

Comment: where's the declaration of the Vue instance in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Your Vue markup is broken. Because it errors it blocks the execution of JavaScript in your page and one of the side effects is the animator doesn't run anymore.

This code is invalid:

```
<div v-for="item in items">
  <h3>{{item1.name1}}</h3>
  <h5 class="prediction-2">Score:{{item2.name2}}%</h5>
  <a v-bind:href="'test.html?id=' + item.other_id" class="btn">
    <span style="color:white;">click here</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

It loops through `items` defining `item` for each iteration but then tries to use `item1` and `item2` (which are not defined).

My advice is to exclude the animator from your question (as it clearly works as intended when there are no errors in the page) and rewrite your question by describing what the Vue code should do.

An example of how a valid `v-for` looks like:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    items: [{
      name: 'Item 1',
      prediction: 56,
      other_id: 101
    }, {
      name: 'Item 2',
      prediction: 82,
      other_id: 102
    }]
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items">
    <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
    <h5 class="prediction-2">Score: {{item.prediction}}%</h5>
    <a :href="'test.html?id=' + item.other_id" class="btn">
      <span>click here</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's looping through each item and rendering them according to each of their values. You'll also notice the links are correct. Without more definition on what the code should actually do/render, I can't help you more.